# Make a horizontal scrollview clickable at a specific spot?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm developing an App on Android Studio and I want to have an easter egg. To do this easter egg, I want people to click on the moon to unlock a new avatar.

**The problem:**

As you can see in the image, the background image is a whole horizontal scrollview and I can't make only a certain part of the horizontal view clickable. This leaderboard page shows up as it is shown on the schema 1 so if you move your finger in the arrow direction, you'll end up on the schema 2, because you've scrolled all the way to the left of the image.

**What i've tried:**

I tried do put the ImageButton inside de image scrollview, I tried to put the ImageButton inside the scrollview after and before the background image, I tried to put it outside the scrollview, after and before also, I tried to put a scrollview inside the existing scrollview, again, after and before the image.

**My question:**

How can I make it so that only the moon on the whole scrollview is clickable? Or is there a away to go around this problem and do this by other means? All help is acceptable, thanks!

[image]

Comment: The moon should be clickable. Is the moon an _ImageButton_ or just part of the _ScrollView's_ background image? Have you checked to make sure the leader board doesn't extend over the moon? If it does, then it would receive the clicks.

Comment: The moon is part of the background image aka scrollview, it's not a ImageButton. The leaderboard doesn't extend.

Comment: You can make the ScrollView clickable and check the touch coordinates to see if the moon was touched. The problem with this approach is how to determine where the moon is in the image, but you may know of some characteristic of the image that might help.